# Laravel with DB2 Database

Tags: php, laravel, db2

Hi guys I'm new with Laravel and I want to use it to build a REST API and the routing is just great my only problem now is the database , I read that Laravel only supports just four database systems http://laravel.com/docs/database#configuration and I need to use IBM DB2 , so is there any alternative to this? I mean like another library and if is possible to integrate with this framework. (I'm not using ODBC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swap out Eloquent and use Doctrine which supports DB2.

Doctrine is on composer so can be easily loaded.